# cloth simulation render

Tags: cloth-simulation

when I play the simulation on a pillow it runs fine in blender but when I render it comes out as follows:
[image]

has anyone run into this before?

The blend file can be found here:
[image]

Comment: the blend file can be found here:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=zxG1RO6K" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/zxG1RO6K/)

Comment: as a general rule: you should bake the cloth sim before rendering....

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you preview the simulation it looks fine, but when you render it looks messed up?  I haven't dug into your cloth settings to find out why it doesn't work at higher subdivisions, which is I'm sure ultimately what you're after, but I did notice right off the bat that the answer to your question lies in the Subdivision modifier:

[image]

You have the number of subdivisions set to 2 in the viewport and 4 on render.  It seems that higher subdivisions are not playing well with your cloth settings, but that should probably be addressed in a new post.

Comment: i tried resolution of 4 and it works fine and smoother look, i just start the simulation again from frame 1 :)